# Why do I get DEBUG level logging in console?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a log4j properties file defined like so:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.github.user=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=target/cucumber-parser.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Based on my understanding, `INFO` level logging should be routed to `stdout` (console) and `DEBUG` should be only written to file. However I get both, `INFO` and `DEBUG` level in console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by applying the below line to `log4j.appender.stdout`:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
```

With this line added to the original configuration that I posted in my original question, only the INFO level logs will be printed to the console and DEBUG will be rerouted to a file as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Because INFO level covers DEBUG level. So that you see both.

See more [Logging Levels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you check [log4j doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html) or [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) you can see more information about levels, but basically: ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF

So log shows the selected level and all the greaters.

Answer (score 0):

add `log4j.additivity.com.github.user=false`.

As in your config, level of `com.github.user` is being set to debug. And besides "file", it will also be additive to root logger, so you can see debug log of `com.github.user` in the console.

In fact, if you write the config this way, splitting loggers and appenders, you can understand better.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.com.github.user=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=target/cucumber-parser.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

For loggers, you specified `com.github.user` to be debug, and all others info with `rootlogger` setting.

Then `com.github.user` will be printed to `file`, and all logs will be printed to console . And if you set the `additivity`, `com.github.user` will be removed from `rootlogger`, so there will only be other logs in console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer however I am noi sure it is going to work in case if the `com.github.user` *is* the root node in project hierarchy. I did try it before and nothing was printed to the console at all.